# How do I hide several divs with PHP?

Tags: php, button, hide

There is a button:

```
<?php echo TbHtml::button(Yii::t('UserModule.main', 'Select Plan'),array('size'=>TbHtml::BUTTON_SIZE_LARGE,'class'=>'btn-select-plan','id'=>'select-free','data-require-payment'=>0,'data-plan'=>Plan::PLAN_ID_FREE));?>
```

There are two fieldsets:

```
    <fieldset class="<?php echo ($requirePayment?'':'hide');?>">
            <div>You need to pay</div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="stripe" class="<?php echo ($requirePayment?'':'hide');?>">

    <legend>
        <span class="register-step">4</span>
        <?php echo Yii::t('UserModule.main', 'Payment Info');?>
    </legend>
    <?php echo TbHtml::alert(TbHtml::ALERT_COLOR_ERROR, '<i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> <span id="stripe-error-message"></span>',array('id'=>'stripe-error','class'=>'hide'));?>
    <?php 
    $paymentError=$stripepayment->hasErrors()?'error':'';
    $paymentError.=' temp-payment-field';
    ?>

    <div class="row-fluid card-info">
        <div class="span6">
            <?php echo TbHtml::textFieldControlGroup('creditcard','',array('groupOptions'=>array('class'=>$paymentError), 'prepend'=>'<i class="icon-credit-card"></i>','id'=>'creditcard','label'=>Yii::t('UserModule.main', 'Credit Card Number <span class="required">*</span>')));?>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <?php echo TbHtml::textFieldControlGroup('cvv','',array('maxlength'=>4,'groupOptions'=>array('class'=>$paymentError),'prepend'=>'<i class="icon-credit-card"></i>','id'=>'cvv','label'=>Yii::t('UserModule.main', 'CVV <span class="required">*</span>')));?>
            <?php //'append'=>'<i class="icon-question" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.Yii::t('content', 'The CVV number is a 3 or 4 digit security code printed on the front or back of your card.').'"></i>',?>
        </div>
    </div></fieldset>
```

If I click the button, why only the second field gets hidden?  I can not fix this bug.

Comment: What are you doing to hide things?  Do you have CSS like `.hide {display: none}` or are you doing something else?

Comment: Sorry. I did not present my question clearly. At beginning, I tried ot do it with CSS. Now, I changed to another method. I used Javascript to manipulate the elements on the page. It is easier to do it with Javascript.